There is no method like "on" and "close" in socket.io-client / socket.io
I'm building a real-time chat application using the MERN stack and Socket.IO. My backend works fine, but I'm encountering issues with the Socket.IO client in my React application. Specifically, when I try to call the on or close methods on the socket instance, they don't seem to work.
Here's my setup:
SocketProvider.js:
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const SocketContext = createContext();

export const useSocketContext = () => {
    return useContext(SocketContext);
};

export const SocketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            const newSocket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
                query: {
                    userId: user._id,
                },
            });

            console.log('New Socket instance:', newSocket);
            console.log('Socket methods:', Object.keys(newSocket));

            newSocket.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('Connected to socket server');
            });

            newSocket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
                console.error('Connection error:', err);
            });

            setSocket(newSocket);

            return () => {
                newSocket.close();
                console.log('Socket disconnected');
            };
        } else {
            if (socket) {
                socket.close();
                setSocket(null);
                console.log('Socket closed due to user logout');
            }
        }
    }, [user]);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
};

useListenMessage.js:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useSocketContext } from '../Context/SocketProvider';
import { RootState } from '../Redux/store';
import { setMessage } from '../Redux/Message/MessageSlice';

export const useListenMessage = (): void => {
    const { socket } = useSocketContext();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const messages = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.message.message);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(messages);
        if (!socket) {
            console.log('Socket not available');
            return;
        }

        const handleMessage = (newMessage) => {
            console.log('Received message:', newMessage);
            dispatch(setMessage([newMessage, ...messages]));
        };

        console.log('Setting up socket listener');
        socket.on('sendMessage', handleMessage);

        // Debugging: print socket instance methods
        console.log('Socket methods:', Object.keys(socket));

        return () => {
            console.log('Cleaning up socket listener');
            socket.off('sendMessage', handleMessage);
        };
    }, [socket, dispatch, messages]);
};

When I console log the methods available on the socket instance, I get:
['connected', 'recovered', 'receiveBuffer', 'sendBuffer', '_queue', '_queueSeq', 'ids', 'acks', 'flags', 'io', 'nsp', '_opts', 'subs', '_callbacks', 'id', '_pid']

I don't see the on or close methods, so my handleMessage function never gets called.

Why has this question been donvoted without a comment?

According to their documentation, use...
import { io } from "socket.io-client"

...and not:
import io from 'socket.io-client';


The important, yet completely unobvious, significance of braces when using ECMAScript Modules strikes again!
